# Draw a bitmap image inside another Bitmap image with specific position android

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap

My question is about making a product inside a pointer on a map programmatily by drawing a bitmap inside another
Goal[0] and Goal[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXwnP.png) are the position x, y. 
See the image to understand more

```
 canvas.drawBitmap(bmpPointer, goal[0] - bmpPointer.getWidth() / 2,goal[1] - bmpPointer.getHeight(), paint);
```

[Example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXwnP.png)

Thank you for you help guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to create image inside the image

but you have to give the shape in which you have to draw

and the rectangle is started from 0 width and 0 height

```
 canvas.drawBitmap(MyBitmap, new Rect(0,0,50,100), rectangle, null);
```